# In Azure, is it possible to retrieve a Backup Policy from a VM tag value?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, backup, policy

## TL;DR

**Is it possible to get the name of a backup policy I'll want to apply, from a Virtual Machine tag value ?** For example : backup=myBackupPolicyDaily1AM or backup=myBackupPolicyWeekly

## Context

In Azure, I have these resources :

- A Recovery Services vault
- Within this Recovery Services vault, a Backup Policy named **DefaultPolicy**
- An Azure policy duplicated from the builtin *Configure backup on VMs with a given tag to an existing recovery services vault in the same location* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-auto-enable-backup#policy-2---configure-backup-on-vms-with-a-given-tag-to-an-existing-recovery-services-vault-in-the-same-location)
- A virtual machine **vmtest01** having a tag **backup=backupme**

## What's working now

I've applied the Azure Policy with these parameters :

- inclusionTagName: **backup**
- inclusionTagValue: **backupme**
- vaultLocation: **West Europe (from dropdown list)**
- backupPolicyId: **DefaultPolicy** (From dropdown list, after selecting my recovery vault)

**Things are working fine so far.** After a Remediation, **vmtest01** is backed up.

## What I want now

Now I want to apply the Backup Policy name I'll have from the **backup** tag value. For example :

- VMs having the tag **backup=myBackupPolicyDaily1AM** will have the **myBackupPolicyDaily1AM** Backup Policy
- VMs having the tag **backup=myBackupPolicyWeekly** will have the **myBackupPolicyWeekly** Backup Policy

I've search on the interwebs and didn't see any example for that use case. Is it possible ?

> Note: All the resources are in the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the **BackupPolicy** variable to `[parameters('inclusionTagValue')]` (~ line 473)?  You will first need to duplicate the built-in policy and make it custom.  I am testing this now but it will take a little time for Azure policy to evaluate and remediate.

```
        "variables": {
          "backupFabric": "Azure",
          "backupPolicy": "[parameters('inclusionTagValue')]",
          "v2VmType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "v2VmContainer": "iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;",
          "v2Vm": "vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;",
          "vaultName": "[take(concat('RSVault-', parameters('location'), '-', guid(resourceGroup().id)),50)]"
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't have this in the backup template I've use, can you tell me from which Policy this snippet come from ?

Comment: I was using the built-in policy named *Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag to a new recovery services vault with a default policy* as a template.

Comment: Thank you ! It was that easy using the right policy template.